# Why does React.StrictMode break calculating a diff of props/state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function SchrödingersDiff()
{
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // simulate a changing state
  useEffect(() =>
  {
    const int = window.setInterval(() => setCount(s => s + 1), 1000);
    return () => window.clearInterval(int);
  }, []);

  const last = useRef(0);
  const diff = useMemo(() =>
  {
    const lastValue = last.current;
    last.current = count;
    const diff = count - lastValue;
    // console.log(diff);
    return diff;
  }, [count]);

  // console.log(diff);
  return diff;
}
```

Why does this component always render "0" when running under `<React.StrictMode>`? It works fine (i.e. renders "1") without strict mode.

I know strict mode renders things twice, which would explain it, but I would expect `useMemo` to catch that - and it does: the log in the memo function prints the correct "1" every second. Even the one outside does.

Is there a better way to calculate that diff?

---

This is my actual `useState`/`useEffect`/`setInterval`, already adapted to keep the last:

```
export function useChannel(channelName, initialData, currentOnly)
{
  const socket = useSc(s => s.socket); // gets a SocketCluster socket
  const [data, setData] = useState(currentOnly ? initialData : {current: initialData});

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    if (!socket) return;

    const channel = socket.subscribe(channelName);
    (async () =>
    {
      for await (const data of channel) setData(currentOnly ? data : s => ({current: data, last: s.current}));
    })();

    return () => channel.unsubscribe();
  }, [socket, channelName]);

  return data;
}
```

Comment: i was thinking you can create a custom hook where you have a piece of state with the current and the last value and in setInterval you update both value at the same time. demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-akituv?file=src/App.js

Comment: IIRC, strict mode does not only render things twice, but also *suppress `console.log` outputs from the second run*. Very confusing indeed.

Comment: "*Is there a better way to calculate that diff?*" - use a reducer, not a state, for `count`, and compute the diff when the count is incremented

Comment: Suppressing the second log would explain things... Unfortunately in reality its not just a simple count that's incremented, its data streamed over websocket. There is a lot of other data flowing through that generic receiving code, so not a good place to calculate something this specific.

Comment: probably best to just keep the last around like @coglialoro suggested. Mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: "*There is a lot of other data flowing through that generic receiving code*" - can you show more of your actual code, please? In what specific place would you prefer to calculate the diff?

Comment: I want to calculate that diff where I render a specific channel's data. That `useChannel` hook has no idea what kind of data its receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to calculate that diff?

I would extract the `useState` hook, and put the calculation logic into the `setState` function. You kinda did that already, but we can make this a bit more generic and reusable:

```
export function useCurrentChannel(channelName, initialData) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialData)
  useChannelSubscription(channelName, setData);
  return data;
}
export function useChannelSubscription(channelName, onNewData) {
  const socket = useSc(s => s.socket);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket) return;

    const channel = socket.subscribe(channelName);
    (async () => {
      for await (const data of channel) {
        onNewData(data);
      }
    })();

    return () => channel.unsubscribe();
  }, [socket, channelName, onNewData]); // or put `onNewData` in a Ref
  return socket;
}
```

Now you can also write

```
export function useHistoricChannel(channelName, initialData) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({current: initialData})
  const handleNewData = useCallback(
    (data) => setData(s => ({current: data, last: s.current})),
    [setData]
  );
  useChannelSubscription(channelName, handleNewData);
  return data;
});
```

which might be nicer with a reducer:

```
export function useHistoricChannel(channelName, initialData) {
  const [data, handleNewData] = useReducer(
    (s, data) => ({current: data, last: s.current}),
    {current: initialData}
  );
  useChannelSubscription(channelName, handleNewData);
  return data;
});
```

Of course you can make the reducer compute anything (like a diff between `current` and `last`), without having to change `useChannelSubscription`.

Comment: seems a bit like overkill, but now I need a channel that keeps accumulating messages. this perfectly accommodates that :)

Comment: @kiw Yes, YAGNI tells us to avoid overkill, and your original simple `useChannel` implementation was perfectly appropriate. But *when* you actually need it, this is the pattern I'd recommend :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `useDiff` custom hook that internally keeps a state with the current and the last values so you can update both from your `setInterval` callback like so:

```
const useDiff = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    current: 0,
    last: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
      setState((s) => ({ current: s.current + 1, last: s.current }));
    }, 1000);
    return () => window.clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return state.current - state.last;
};
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-akituv

Comment: That requires the interval to be aware of the diff, though

Comment: @Bergi I added a version that uses `useReducer` in my stackblitz, hope I understood what you meant

Comment: @Bergi it just needs to know to keep the last, not that I want to calculate `(current.packetsLost - last.packetsLost) / (current.packetsSent - last.packetsSent)`

Comment: @coglialoro More or less, yes. See my answer for what I had in mind :-)